# How to format a Date variable in LWUIT?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have an object whose class has a getter method , and this getter method returns a Date value. I want to show this value in a Label in the format DD/MM/YYYY.

How to achieve that with LWUIT ?

Thank you very much indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to convert date to string format and pass the this string value to label.

```
   public static String dateToString (long date)
             {
             Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
             c.setTime(new Date(date));
             int y = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
             int m = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
             int d = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
             String t = (d<10? "0": "")+d+"/"+(m<10? "0": "")+m+"/"+(y<10? "0": "")+y;
             return t;
             }
```

Answer (score 2):

To thank you here is a code of mine which formats a number :

```
public static String formatNombre(int trivialNombre, String separateur)
    {
        String pNombre, sNombreLeads, sNombre, argNombre, resultat;
        int leadingBits;
        int nbBit;

        pNombre = String.valueOf(trivialNombre);

        if (pNombre.length() > 3)
        {
            leadingBits = (pNombre.length())%3;

            if (leadingBits != 0)
                sNombreLeads = pNombre.substring(0, leadingBits).concat(separateur);
            else
                sNombreLeads = "";

            nbBit = 0;
            sNombre = "";
            argNombre = pNombre.substring(leadingBits);
            for (int i=0;i<argNombre.length();i++)
            {
                sNombre = sNombre.concat(String.valueOf(argNombre.charAt(i)));
                nbBit++;
                if (nbBit%3 == 0)
                    sNombre = sNombre.concat(separateur);
            }
            sNombre = sNombre.substring(0, sNombre.length() - 1);
            resultat = sNombreLeads.concat(sNombre);
            return resultat;
        }
        else
            return pNombre;
    }
```